# How to registry a service from different IP address?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I'm learning about Microservices with Eureka & Spring Boot. I've already known how and successfully registered all services into Eureka, but all services and Eureka are created on Localhost. I wonder, can I stores services from other computer and still be able to register to Eureka in this Computer, and how to do it? Is there any documents for my question? Because I looked up to Eureka documents and all of them are about create eureka and services only on localhost.
Thank you everyone!

Here is my eureka-server: application.properties

```
spring.application.name=netflix-eureka-server
server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Here is my product-management-service: application.properties

```
spring.application.name=product-management-service
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
server.port=8077
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution for my problem
Firstly, I add 2 more lines of code to application.properties of my computer xxx.xxx.xxx.166 which to tell eureka from this computer that services will register from IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.124:

```
spring.application.name=netflix-eureka-server
server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

#add these lines which is the IP address of my another computer
spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple.local.uri=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.124
eureka.instance.appname=xxx.xxx.xxx.124
```

Secondly, I config application.properties of my Another computer by add some lines to file:

```
spring.application.name=product-management-service
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka

#new code start here
eureka.client.prefer-same-zone-eureka=false
eureka.client.proxy-host=xxx.xxx.xxx.166
eureka.client.proxy-port=8761

server.address=192.168.11.124
server.port=8077

#configuration to set the ip of host instead of the default localhost
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.instance.hostname=${server.address}
eureka.instance.ip-address=${server.address}
eureka.instance.instance-id=${server.address}:${spring.application.name}:${server.port}
#new code end here
```

And here is my result [Eureka](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5V8k.png).

I hope to see more and better suggestion about this situation from everyone.

Hope this could help someone xD.